# Executar a ação de um form sem atualizar a página no django

Tags: javascript, html5, django, django-templates, django3

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde preciso adicionar membros a um grupo, pra isso, percorro todos os membros cadastrados e apresento no meu template html. Cada membro tem ao lado o botão "adicionar" só que sempre ao fazer isso, ele atualiza a página... Gostaria de saber como fazer isso sem precisar atualizar, ou seja, clico em adicionar e ele já está adicionado automaticamente.

views.py

```
def adicionar_membros(request, id):
    plan=Planejamento.objects.get(id=id)
    usuarios = User.objects.all() # estendi o modelo padrão de usuarios do django

    return render(request,'site/adicionar_membros.html', {'plan':plan, 'usuarios':usuarios})
```

adicionar_membros.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Adicionar Membros {%endblock%}

{% block content %}

  <section id="team" class="team2">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="row">
        {% for i in usuarios %}
            <h4>{{i.first_name}}</h4>
            <form method="POST">
               {% csrf_token %}
               <input type="submit">Adicionar</input>
            </form>
        {%endfor%}

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando AJAX você consegue facilmente, mas para isso vamos usar uma ferramenta especial, e configurar da forma correta.

Primeiro você precisa instalar o [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Ele é um client http que pode ser adicionado ao seu html pela tag script como você pode ver na documentação.

O que vamos fazer?

1. Pegar o momento em que o botão é clicado.
2. Enviar para o django por meio do axios.

Para você enviar um form por AJAX o Django requer, que você especifique que ele é um  `multipart/form-data`
Dessa forma

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

E o seu Input deve ter um atributo 'name', para que o django possa pegar o valor dele na view. Quando o usuário submeter o form você deve capturar o evento

```
let form = document.getElementById('form'); // selecting the form

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { // adiciona o listener para o submit
    event.preventDefault()//previne comportamento padrão
    
    let data = new FormData(form); // Junta os dados do formulário
```

Logo após você deve realizar uma requisição no axios, enviado a variável data.

```
    axios.post('url-da-view', data, config)
    .then((res)=>{
       //aplique as mudanças no DOM aqui
    })
    .catch((erros)=>{
      //Pegue os erros aqui.
    })
```

Beleza, parece que terminamos certo? NOP. Tá vendo aquela variável config, na chamada do axios? Ali temos que enviar um cookie para o django, para que o back-end se proteja de ataques CSRF. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) do Django devemos copiar a seguinte função para pegar o cookie:

```
function getCookie(name) {
let cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;}

const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Para enviarmos esse cookie no axios usamos aquela variável config (antes de enviar a requisição)

```
const config = {
    // O nome do header é o Django que dá, por padrão. Mas você pode mudar nas configurações.
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', //Aqui você passa o formato novamente.
    }
}
```

Logo após ajustar as configurações, você envia sua requisição axios.
Eu recomento a você usar colocar um input hidden com o valor da pk ou do nome do usuário que você quer adicionar, para o django pegar esse valor na view, baseado no nome do input, e possa fazer as querysets. Supondo que seu input sem o nome 'user':

```
request.POST['user']
```

Comment: Obrigado Rubens, Axios não conheço, só ouvi falar sobre o Ajax. Irei pesquisar sobre para entender melhor o que você me orientou, desde já agradeço demais a resposta detalhada desta forma, Valeu!!!

Comment: Tmj. Além do axios tem o jquery, eu só não falei dele pelo fato de o axios ter esse foco nessa funcionalidade de fazer requisição, já que o jquery tem outras muitas coisas que talvez você nem use. Mas caso você já use jquery no projeto, você pode tentar ajax nele também.